# Failed to load zfs modules after kernel update with secure boot enabled, dkms seems fine

Tags: boot, kernel, zfs

Ubuntu 23.10

After kernel update to 6.5.0-15, system fails to load zfs modules on boot. I've had this problem before and solved it by dpkg-reconfiguring zfs-dkms. This time it seems to be already configured for the running kernel and reconfiguring it again does nothing.

I am aware I can "solve" this by turning secure boot off (which is what I'm currently doing) or rolling back to previous kernel version (probably, didn't actually try, should work).

```
» dkms status                                                                                                                 
zfs/2.2.0, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
» uname -a                                                                                                                    
Linux swiftmoon 6.5.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jan  9 17:03:36 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From the apt logs:

```
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic (6.5.0-15.15) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic
Setting up linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.5.0.15.17) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (6.5.0.15.17) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic (6.5.0-15.15) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-15-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-15-generic................
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/zfs/2.2.0/build/module/zfs.ko
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/zfs/2.2.0/build/module/spl.ko

Running the post_build script:
Cleaning build area...
```

(skip)

```
zfs.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
Module version 2.2.0-0ubuntu1~23.10 for zfs.ko.zst
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 6.5.0-15-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

spl.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
Module version 2.2.0-0ubuntu1~23.10 for spl.ko.zst
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 6.5.0-15-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.
depmod...
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-15-generic/x86_64 succeeded for zfs
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-15-generic
   ...done.
```

EDIT: Solved by removing zfs-dkms. Turned out I was living in the past and it wasn't needed at all, as was pointed out in the comments.

EDIT_2: System completely froze about 30 minutes of idle time later, upon reboot would load to recovery mode and freeze on starting up login manager. Fixed by rolling back zfs snapshot. Can't find anything useful in logs as of yet. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Why do you have the `zfs-dkms` package? The zfs kernel modules come with the standard `linux-image-*-generic[-hwe]` kernel (and have for ages).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. As far as I remember, I installed it back when I was using mainline kernel in 20.04, and then kept it after I stopped using mainline kernel because I forgot and everything was working.